# Python - Select from sqlite tables by passing multiple arguments

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am trying to build a webapp in Flask and SQLite and I have a table with columns: Date, Country and Name and I'm doing a request form on these data

```
country = request.form.getlist('country')
name = request.form.getlist('name')

str_from_date = request.form.get('from_date')
str_to_date = request.form.get('to_date')
from_date = dt.datetime.strptime(str_from_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
to_date = dt.datetime.strptime(str_to_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

And I'm trying to pass these arguments into sql select statement
i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE country_col IN {country} AND name_col IN {name}
AND date(date_col) >= {from_date} AND date(date_col) <= {to_date}
```

But I can't find a way to do it when passing more than one argument so right now all I have is this because cur.execute does not take more than one argument

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE country_col IN ({co}) ORDER BY datetime(date_col) ASC'.format(co=','.join(['?'] * len(country)))
data = cur.execute(sql, country).fetchall()
```

I want a way where I can pass multiple arguments into the sql select statement in order to query for the data accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can run SQL against your SQLite instance, instead of Python. That way it is easier to find issue with SQL statement - one layer less.

I see potential issue with syntax of your query. When `{country}` is used, then Python puts `Canada`, `Poland` as string. However SQLite expects value which should be `'Canada'`, `'Poland'`.

Other then that `IN` operator checks if field exists in provided list - that is why you need `(`, `)` - to construct list with one element. Better operator here is `=`.

If I'm touching operators... Please read about `BETWEEN` [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/between.php).

Next. I'm not sure what is stored in `from_date` / `to_date` columns. Please read  [SQLite docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to be sure if it is used properly.

So with proposed changes I would like to see:

```
sql = f"""SELECT * 
 FROM table 
 WHERE country_col = '{country}' 
  AND name_col = '{name}'
  AND date(date_col) BETWEEN '{from_date}' AND '{to_date}'"""
```

### Update

To pass array. Let's start with basic SQL:

select * from table where country_col in ('Poland', 'Canada', 'Germany')

To read more, check [this](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-in/) site. Just remember that string should be surrounded by `'`. Sometimes it can be also `"`, but for PostgreSQL `"col"` - means column name `col`, while `'col'` means string `col`. So your `IN` operator was right one!

Now from Python - you need to prepare string with country names, each surrounded by `'`:

```
countries = ['Poland', 'Germany', 'France']
param = ", ".join([f"'{x}'" for x in countries])
```

`join` concatenates strings from passed list, inner [comprehension](https://diveinto.org/python3/comprehensions.html) adds `'` to each item of the list.

Together:

```
countries = ['Poland', 'Germany', 'France']
param = ", ".join([f"'{x}'" for x in countries])                                                                                                                                                                                           
sql = f"""SELECT * 
 FROM table 
 WHERE country_col in ({param})' 
  AND name_col = '{name}'
  AND date(date_col) BETWEEN '{from_date}' AND '{to_date}'"""
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. That makes more sense. However, I still have the issue of how to pass multiple arrays into the sql statement that I don't know how to solve. I'd appreciate any help with that. Also, if you don't mind answering, what does the f in front of the sql statement mean?

Answer (score 0):

The first way I would think of doing this is by generating the query manually:

```py
country = {
  "col": col1,
  "type": None, 
  "q": "IN", 
  "data": request.form.getlist('country')
}

name = {
  "col": col2, 
  "type": None, 
  "q": "IN", 
  "data": request.form.getlist('name')
}

str_from_date = request.form.get('from_date')
str_to_date = request.form.get('to_date')

from_date = {
  "col": col3, 
  "type": "date", 
  "q": ">=", 
  "data": dt.datetime.strptime(str_from_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
}

to_date = {
  "col": col4, 
  "type": "date", 
  "q": "<=", 
  "data": dt.datetime.strptime(str_to_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
}

all_data = [country, name_col, from_date, to_date]

q = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE "

for i, d in enumerate():
  _col = f"date({d['col']})" if d["type"] == "date" else d["col"]
  q += f"{'AND ' if i > 0 else ''}{d['col']} {d['q']} ({['?'] * len(d['data'])}) "

data = cur.execute(q, [d["data"] for d in all_data]).fetchall()
```

I don't know if this is the desired approach but I guess it would work.